# Base class to Derived class in Iteration

Tags: c#, .net

I have this base class that has some properties. In my derived class this is where I wanted to implement some computation (addition and subtraction for example).

I implemented a list of base class. `List<A>`. In my Iteration (foreach), I have to implement the the derived class to do computation (sample computation - addition).
How  can we implement this? Please let me know if not clear.

```
public class A {
  public int value1 { get; set;}
  public int value2 { get; set;}
  public virtual int sum { get { return 0 ;} }
}

public class B : A {
  public override int sum {
     get {
        return value1 + value2;
     }
  }
}



 List<A> collection = new List<A>();

 collection.Add(new A { value1 = 1, value2 = 1 });
 collection.Add(new A { value1 = 2, value2 = 2 });
 collection.Add(new A { value1 = 3, value2 = 3 });

 foreach (var item in collection.OfType<B>())
 {
    Console.WriteLine(item.sum);
 }
```

Comment: It's completely unclear what problems you have with current approach

Comment: It sounds like you need to cast but its unclear what you are trying do however... How do you plan on guarranteeing that every object in your list is a *B* object? and if they are, why isn't it a list of `B`?

Comment: If your `List<A>` contains `B` instance runtime will call `B.Sum`. I believe that's what you're asking about.

Comment: It sounds like maybe you are using inheritance when in fact you want something like the Strategy Pattern. You seem to want to use a list of objects of a single type, and then choose the concrete summation logic at runtime.

Comment: Hi, I added the iteration code. which is code is exited on the foreach loop.

Comment: In your updated post above, simply create the objects you're adding as `new B`, and take out the `OfType<B>`. Everything will then work as you expect. That is exactly what polymorphism is meant to do.

Comment: @Baldrick, could you provide a simple example? I will really appreciate that :)

Comment: @Ian: Done as requested! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, just use the following code:

```
List<A> collection = new List<A>();

collection.Add(new B { value1 = 1, value2 = 1 });
collection.Add(new B { value1 = 2, value2 = 2 });
collection.Add(new B { value1 = 3, value2 = 3 });

foreach (var item in collection)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item.sum);
}
```

The `sum` method will be resolved at runtime to the method on `B`, and everything should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just modify this as mentioned in the comment above

```
collection.Add(new A { value1 = 1, value2 = 1 });
 collection.Add(new A { value1 = 2, value2 = 2 });
 collection.Add(new A { value1 = 3, value2 = 3 });

 foreach (var item in collection.OfType<B>())
 {
    Console.WriteLine(item.sum);
 }
```

to this and it should work

```
collection.Add(new B { value1 = 1, value2 = 1 });
 collection.Add(new B { value1 = 2, value2 = 2 });
 collection.Add(new B { value1 = 3, value2 = 3 });

 foreach (var item in collection)
 {
    Console.WriteLine(item.sum);
 }
```

That's because in your sample every instance of Type A is just Type A and every instance of Type B is Type B AND Type A.